# Git cannot pull, commit stash or revert changes

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

When trying to pull with git I constantly get this error:

> "Your local changes would be overwritten by merge. Commit, stash or revert them to proceed. "

I have looked for this error on multiple sites including StackOverflow. If I view the files which cause a conflict, I see that it is about files which are not in my github repo. They are local files.

As far as I know the only way to keep all my local files and pull the rest from git is by using commit (based on the options stash, commit or revert). I did this but I still get the same error.

I haven't added those local files to my github repo though, but I want to keep these files local, so as far as I know I should not do this.

I am using PhpStorm's built in git feature. I know there are questions on StackOverflow with the same error. I tried most of these solutions however, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: maybe you forgot to `git add` some local files to your repository?

Comment: i am not sure, but i do not want those files on git. Is it correct that i should not add then them?

Comment: If these files are needed to go along with the other changes that you committed, then yes, you should add them.  Otherwise, it's hard to answer without knowing what files they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to brute force reset followed by a git pull to update, you can do:

```
git reset --hard
```

and then try pulling again.  This will totally clear out your uncommitted changes.  Only do this if that's really what you want to do.

If you still have errors after that, maybe you have some local files that would be overwritten by the pull.  You can clear them all out with the command:

```
git clean -f
```

Although again, you want to be careful that you actually want these files removed.  Once you `git clean` you cannot undo it.  To be sure, inspect your current state using:

```
git status
```

Comment: i want to keep my changes. I did a commit, but it did not matter.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to update my branch :

`git stash`

`git fetch`

`git rebase`

`git stash apply` 
  and resolve conflict

`git stash clear`

You can do a commit too